# How to pass function required from another .js file into an index.ejs view via app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**graphs.js**: contains a function that makes an API call and returns an object with an HTML link that will be used to embed a graph.

**app.js**: contains the following **(graphs.js has been required)**:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var graphs = require("graphs"); <---

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
    CAN I PASS THE FUNCTION THROUGH HERE?
});

//server
app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Dev server started!");
});
```

**index.ejs**: I am attempting to pass the **graphs.graph** API function call through app.js so it is usable and executed in my index.ejs

For example:

```
<div class="graph-test">
    <% graphs.graph() %>
</div>
```

Any advice, best practice comments, or any other methods of doing this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you wouldnot send a function through `res.render()`. The practice is you deal which your `logic/process` in your route or controller first and then send only computed data into to template engine. It might be confusing some time as you can also write `js` in your template engine, but **template engine only replaces variables in a template file with actual values, and transforms the template into an HTML file sent to the client**. Like below:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
   var data = graphs.graph();
   res.render("index", {data: data});
});
```

And talking about your specific problem, If your API call is done from server-side, then you should do like above. If your API call should be done through client-side then you can embed the `js` file into your view.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it helped clear up some things. Is there any real benefit to doing server-side API call vs client-side, seeing how it would change how I use the data via my router or embedding it directly?

Comment: Call can be done from both side, but when calling to certain APIs [CORS] prevents JavaScript from making requests across domain boundaries. So, for them call must be done in backend/server-side.

Comment: Thank you Tolsee.  I have marked your solution as the best answer because it got me to where I wanted to go.  Appreciate your help!